# BeautifulSoup limits to two decimals, and integers that start with 0.00 results in "0.0"

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

The goal of this app is to print the prices of cryptocurrencies. It prints the prices of the 100 currencies on the first page on [coinmarketcap](https://coinmarketcap.com/), however, it only records up to two decimals and I don't know why. When the int starts with 0.00 the application only prints 0.0. Why?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/"
result = requests.get(url).text
doc = BeautifulSoup(result, "html.parser")
tbody = doc.tbody
trs = tbody.contents


for tr in trs[:10]:

    price = tr.contents[4]
    price = price.text
```

HTML changes here, so new code is in order.

```
for tr in trs[10:]:

    try:
        price = tr.contents
        price = str(price)
        price = price.split("$<!-- -->", 1)[1]
        price = price.split("</span></td", 1)[0]

        price = float(price)

    finally:
        pass

    print(price)
    print()
```

I've tried using Selenium to extract the information, but I only want to use BeautifulSoup.

Answer (score 0):

Your program says that the price is zero because that’s what the HTML says. When I visit https://coinmarketcap.com/ in a browser with scripting disabled, it tells me that eCash is worth “$0.00”. If I turn scripting back on and refresh the page, then it tells me that it’s worth “$0.0002358”.

Instead of parsing the HTML, you could try using the [CoinMarketCap API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/).

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are converting the price which is a `string` to a `float`. *See below*

```py
>>> float('0.00')
0.0
```

Also, I don't see any difference between `0.00` and `0.0`. Both values are same.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = "https://coinmarketcap.com/"
result = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(result, "lxml")

t = soup.find('table', class_='cmc-table').find('tbody')
trs = t.find_all('tr')
for tr in trs:
    tds = tr.find_all('td')
    name = tds[2].text.strip()
    price = tds[3].text.strip()
    print(f'{name}\t{price}')
```

Sample output where price is `$0.00` - *I did not convert the price to `float`*

```
eCashXEC    $0.00
SHIBA INUSHIB   $0.00
BitTorrentBTT   $0.00
```